# One monitor has an orange tint while the other does not

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, mojave

My macbookpro is connected to two external monitors.

The monitors are Dell U2715H

[image]

However somehow on one of the monitors looks like the night shift is turned on, and the other are not.

[image]

1. If I tried toggling the night shift setting, the orange tint just
   switches screen.
2. I have tried unplug and plug. The effect stays the same.
3. I have tried the built-in monitor and fiddled brightness and
   contracts settings. No effect. There is also not other color
   temperature options.

Is there anything I can do to fix it without restarting the machine?

It is a 'MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)' running 10.14.6

Comment: What monitor (specific make/model)? Also have you tried adjusting the monitor using it's built in controls?

Comment: Dell U2715H. Added to the question.

Comment: And Dell's monitors have adjustments built into them. You may want to indicate what adjusting those settings resulted in. This looks a lot like an incorrect white-point setting on the monitor itself.

Comment: See what I tried at point 1. The orange tint effect switches from one to another. It is an OS issue.

Comment: I'd test combinations of screens & just switch night shift off wherever you can get it to appear, reboot in between. I have 2 very similar Dell screens & I've never seen the night shift tab for either of them.

Comment: Since this comes up pretty high on google for relevant search requests: This behaviour can also happen for some Displays when True Tone is activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mismatch is fixed after a reboot.